# Hit testing for a maze

Tags: actionscript-3

I am making a maze game and i have the edge of the maze as a movieclip. I'm trying to test if the player hit tests the maze to make him stop using this code.

```
If(player.hitTestObject(Maze))
{
  function()
}
```

But wether or not It's actually touching the maze (it's in the empty space on the inside) it always registers as touching. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You probably want to use BitmapData.hitTest. Here's a good example: [link](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/06/24/using-bitmapdata-hittest-for-collision-detection/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't have to use any physics api. They are too heavy and complex and your task is simple. Try replacing your hitTest method for hitTestPoint

```
if(Maze.hitTestPoint(player.x,player.y))
{
  function()
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're looking for:

http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/06/24/using-bitmapdata-hittest-for-collision-detection/

The reason why hitTest always says true, is that it only checks to see if the **bounding boxes** for the two objects touch each other. More nfo on what that means can probably be found in the link above. What is in the link above, is an explanation of how to do pixel-perfect hit tests in flash. :) Also if you're doing a game using collision like this and/or any kind of physics, you may be interest in this tutorial:

http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=135

It's a video about a world construction kit for Box2D, probably the most popular physics library for flash.

Comment: Thats what i figured. I looked it up and it says flash draws a hit test rectangle around the object which is bad for anything other than rectangles. Thanks for the links!

Comment: No problem and yes this is true. Even if you had a diamond shape, flash would draw a rectangle on a 90 degree angle to encompass it. You can see this visually by right clicking in flash player and enabling "show redraw regions."